# Give the proof of the inequality $0.5(|A+B|+|A-B|)= \max (|A|,|B|)$

Tags: inequality

$$0.5(|A+B|+|A-B|)= \max (|A|,|B|)$$
where $A$ and $B$ are any values (real number)

I have tried to solve this using triangle inequality but got $0.5(|A+B|+|A-B|)> |A|$
How to prove the given inequality??

Comment: You should not have gotten a strict inequality, since this equation clearly does hold when $A = B$! Also, you should use LaTeX to format your posts, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a quick guide.

Comment: In general, to show that some quantity $x$ equals $\max(\lvert A \rvert, \lvert B \rvert)$, you must show that $x \geq \lvert A \rvert$, $x \geq \lvert B \rvert$, and if $y$ is any other number such that $y \geq \lvert A \rvert$ and $y \geq \lvert B \rvert$, then $y \geq x$.

Comment: Your title calls it an "inequality" but then you said $\text{“}{=}\text{”}$ rather than $\text{“}{\le}\text{.”} \qquad$

Answer (score 1):

WLOG, $A\ge B\ge0$ because swapping $A,B$ and/or changing one or two signs has no effect.

Then the identity reduces to

$$\frac{A+B+A-B}2=A,$$ which is true.

Comment: I'm curious if there is such simple formula for $\max(A,B)$, too.

Comment: I don't think so. Let $A=-4$ and $B=3$. Then this formula gives $$\frac{|-4+3|+|-4-3|}{2} = 4$$ This is $\max(|A|,|B|)$ but not $\max(A,B)$

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you dropped the absolute values.

Comment: No worries. I think this one works fine for all $A$ and $B$ such that $A+B\ge0$. I would appreciate if you could let me know once you find out something workable :)

Comment: The following looks workable $$\max(a,b) = \frac{a+b+|a-b|}{2}$$ Do you agree?

Comment: A typographical difference:
$$
\begin{align}
& \frac{|-4+3|+|-4-3|}{2} = 4 \\ {} \\
& \frac{\left|-4+3\right|+\left|-4-3\right|}{2} = 4
\end{align}
$$
Sometimes `\left` and `\right` result in proper horizontal spacing. (Some people don't notice things like this.) @VIVID

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks for this. I didn't know `\left` `\right` were supposed to be used in this case.

Comment: @VIVID Yes, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3892608/recall-max-x-1-x-2-fracx-1x-22-fracx-1-x-22-using-this-identi/

Answer (score 1):

I will assume here that you meant $0.5(|A+B|+|A-B|) \le \max \{|A|,|B|\}$ rather than $0.5(|A+B|+|A-B|) = \max \{|A|,|B|\}.$

As often happens with absolute values, it is useful to consider two cases:

- $A,B$ have the same sign (i.e. both are positive or both negative).
- $A,B$ have different signs.

No generality is lost by assuming $|A|\ge|B|,$ i.e. whichever one of $A,B$ has the larger absolute value will be called $A$ and the other $B.$  Then $\max\{|A|,|B|\} = |A|.$

If $A,B$ are both positive you have
\begin{align}
& 0.5(|A+B|+|A-B|) \\[6pt]
= {} & 0.5(A+B) + 0.5|A-B| \\[6pt]
\le {} & 0.5(A+B) \le 0.5(A+A) = A = \max\{|A|,|B|\}.
\end{align}
If both are negative then a similar argument works.

Now suppose one is positive and one negative. Then $|A-B| = |A|+|B|,$ and so
\begin{align}
& 0.5(|A+B|+|A-B|) \\[6pt]
= & 0.5(|A|+|B|) + 0.5|A+B| \\[6pt]
\le {} & 0.5(|A|+|A|) = |A| = \max\{|A|,|B|\}.
\end{align}

Comment: What do you think about the question I posted as a comment under Yves's answer?

Comment: Equality holds in all cases. By the way, $0.5(A+B)+0.5|A-B|\le(A+B)$ does not seem so true...